# Visual Studio: multiple solutions or build configurations?

Tags: visual-studio, build, architecture, project, solution

We have multiple projects, which can be roughly grouped into 3 groups: A, B & C. A-projects and B-projects depend on C-projects, but A and B are not dependent on each other.
I see two major possible architectures:

1. Have one solution with all projects, and define build configurations (so when I build A, I won't build B)
2. Have 2 solutions (A, B), and have the C-projects included in both.

Which one is preferred? Or is there better architecture?